# Mysql group concat only if selected column table A match table B

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables.

table tyre

```
+------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------+-------+------+
| sku                          | tyrename                                                       | width  | ratio | size |
+------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------+-------+------+
| 2454019RE003(98W)            | 245/40 R19 98W BRIDGESTONE Potenza RE003                       | 245.00 | 40.00 |   19 |
| 2753519RE003(100W)XL         | 275/35 R19 100W BRIDGESTONE Potenza RE003 XL                   | 275.00 | 35.00 |   19 |
| 2454019CSC5P(98Y)XL(EU)      | 245/40 R19 98Y CONTINENTAL ContiSportContact 5P XL (EU)        | 245.00 | 40.00 |   19 |
| 2454518CSC3(96W)(EU)         | 245/45 R18 96W CONTINENTAL ContiSportContact3 (EU)             | 245.00 | 45.00 |   18 |
| 2454518CSC3(96Y)ESSR(EU)     | 245/45 R18 96Y CONTINENTAL ContiSportContact3 E SSR (EU)       | 245.00 | 45.00 |   18 |
+------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------+-------+------+
```

and table vehicle

```
+------+------+---------------+-------------------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| make | year | modeltrim     | options                       | tyre1_1 | tyre1_2 | tyre1_3 | tyre2_1 | tyre2_2 | tyre2_3 |
+------+------+---------------+-------------------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| BMW  | 2014 | 5 Series 535i | OE Fitment 01 (18")           |  245.00 |   45.00 |   18.00 |    0.00 |    0.00 |    0.00 |
| BMW  | 2014 | 5 Series 535i | OE Fitment 02 (18")           |  245.00 |   50.00 |   18.00 |    0.00 |    0.00 |    0.00 |
| BMW  | 2014 | 5 Series 535i | OE Fitment 03 (17")           |  225.00 |   55.00 |   17.00 |    0.00 |    0.00 |    0.00 |
| BMW  | 2014 | 5 Series 535i | OE Fitment 04 Staggered (19") |  245.00 |   40.00 |   19.00 |  275.00 |   35.00 |   19.00 |
| BMW  | 2014 | 5 Series 535i | Option 01 Staggered (19")     |  245.00 |   40.00 |   19.00 |  265.00 |   45.00 |   19.00 |
+------+------+---------------+-------------------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

I want to group sku into 1 column to produce table like following, joining 2 table using tyre width, ratio and size.

```
+------+------+---------------+-------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| make | year | modeltrim     | options                       | sku                                                             |
+------+------+---------------+-------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| BMW  | 2014 | 5 Series 535i | OE Fitment 01 (18")           |  2454518CSC3(96W)(EU),2454518CSC3(96Y)ESSR(EU)                  |
| BMW  | 2014 | 5 Series 535i | OE Fitment 04 Staggered (19") |  2454019RE003(98W),2454019CSC5P(98Y)XL(EU),2753519RE003(100W)XL |
+------+------+---------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+---------------+
```

Some options having 2 tyre size and only show the row if both sizes having matches with tyre width, ratio size; if only 1 size match with tyre table, dont show the row.

currently I'm using the below sql query but it shows the row even only 1 tyre size is match for those option with 2 tyre size. With the above example table, the below query will show the row for 'Option 01 Staggered (19")' even though there's no tyre size 265/45/19 in tyre table.

```
SELECT unionTable.make, unionTable.year, unionTable.modeltrim, unionTable.options, group_concat(unionTable.sku order by unionTable.sku)
FROM
(SELECT
    a.make, a.modeltrim, a.year, a.options, b.sku
FROM
    vehicle a
        JOIN
    tyre b
WHERE
    a.tyre1_1 = b.width AND a.tyre1_2 = b.ratio
        AND a.tyre1_3 = b.size
UNION ALL
SELECT
    a.make, a.modeltrim, a.year, a.options, b.sku
FROM
    vehicle a
        JOIN
    tyre b
WHERE
    a.tyre2_1 = b.width AND a.tyre2_2 = b.ratio
        AND a.tyre2_3 = b.size) AS unionTable
group by unionTable.make, unionTable.modeltrim, unionTable.year, unionTable.options
order by unionTable.make, unionTable.modeltrim, unionTable.year, unionTable.options, unionTable.sku
```

Thank you.

Comment: If you down vote, please leave a comment saying why.

Comment: Any time you have enumerated columns (above, say, '2'), alarm bells should start ringing. See normalisation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use inner join and group_concat

```
select  a.make, a.year,  a.modeltrim, a.options , group_concat(b.sku)
from  vehicle as a
inner join tyre as b on ( b.tyre1_1 = a.width AND b.tyre1_2 = a.ratio
    AND b.tyre1_3 = a.size)
gruop by a.make, a.year,  a.modeltrim, a.options
UNION     
select  a.make, a.year,  a.modeltrim, a.options , group_concat(b.sku)
from  vehicle as a
inner join tyre as b on ( b.tyre2_1 = a.width AND b.tyre2_2 = a.ratio AND b.tyre2_3 = a.size) )
gruop by a.make, a.year,  a.modeltrim, a.options
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however your query only match the first tyre size and some vehicle having the option of 2 tyre size (tyre2_1, tyre2_2 and tyre2_3) and I need to match these as well into the group concat. Another problem is for option with 2 tyre sizes, if either 1 sizes do not have matched width, ratio and size in tyre table, the row need to be excluded. For those options with 2 tyre sizes, both sizes must have matching tyre sizes in tyre table to be included in the result.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your update. However, the query did not check if there're value in both tyre1_x and tyre2_x columns then both of these tyre size need to have matching sku in tyre table, else if only match either tyre1_x or tyre2_x then dont include the row.